# Loading images from tensor strings

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a Tensorflow dataset of strings (where each string is a path to a dicom image) and I want to map a preprocessing function to the dataset. The preprocessing function is supposed to load the pixel array from the dicom file using the `pydicom` package. But when I try to map a function though I get an Attribute error. How can I read a string value from a tensor using a function like below? I am using Tensorflow 2.0.0 and pydicom 1.3.0.

```
AttributeError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-12-eff65198c202>:12 load_and_preprocess_image  *
        dicom_data = pydicom.dcmread(img_path)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydicom/filereader.py:849 dcmread  *
        dataset = read_partial(fp, stop_when, defer_size=defer_size,
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydicom/filereader.py:651 read_partial  *
        preamble = read_preamble(fileobj, force)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydicom/filereader.py:589 read_preamble  *
        preamble = fp.read(128)

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Here is my code that creates the dataset and maps a preprocessing function to it.

```
def load_and_preprocess_image(img_path):
    """ Load image, resize, and normalize the image"""
    dicom_data = pydicom.dcmread(img_path))
    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(dicom_data.pixel_array, dtype=tf.float32)
    return image

# Create dataset (list of strings that lead to dicom paths)
image_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dicom_files_list)

# Map a preprocessing function to list of dicom paths
image_train_ds = image_train_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a Tensorflow-io package that now allows this. its fairly straightforward.

1. Install the package:

```
pip install -q tensorflow-io
```

2. 

```
import tensorflow_io as tfio

def load_and_preprocess_image(img_path):
    _bytes = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    dicom_data = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(_bytes, dtype=tf.float32)
    return dicom_data

dicom_files_list = ['path/to/dicom']

# Create dataset (list of strings that lead to dicom paths)
image_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dicom_files_list)
image_train_ds = image_train_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `pydicom.dcmread(img_path)`, `img_path` is tf.string tensor. I don't think `pydicom` support to read tensor object.

I found a workaround which is [gradient_decode_dicom](https://github.com/gradienthealth/gradient_decode_dicom) that provides DICOM operation in tensorflow. The following codes is adapted from [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MdjXN3XkYs_mSyVtdRK7zaCbzkjGub_B?pli=1&authuser=1#scrollTo=c21lFqBtfpxc), and tested on tf2.0.

```py
def load_and_preprocess_image(img_path):
    _bytes = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    dicom_data = decode_dicom_image(_bytes, dtype=tf.float32)
    return dicom_data

dicom_files_list = ['path/to/dicom']

# Create dataset (list of strings that lead to dicom paths)
image_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dicom_files_list)
image_train_ds = image_train_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image)
```